# Inconsistent CPU performance for simple 2 line program. C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, performance, cpu

Here's a problem I'm having. I've a server and a laptop. Both computers have nothing running on them.

Here's the program:

```
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
        while( true )
        {
            w.Restart();
            for( int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++ )
                ;

            w.Stop();

            System.Console.WriteLine( w.ElapsedMilliseconds );
        }
    }
```

On my laptop I get consistent performance around 650 miliseconds. On the server I get crazy swings. Anything from 595 to 1500 miliseconds. Again both computers have nothing running on them. The program is so simple it doesn't even use RAM. Just registers probably.

What can cause this? I tested the server and the laptop with passmark.com benchmark and everything looks normal.

Here are the specs for the server:
windows 2012 x64
cpu: xeon e5-1620 @ 3.6

Here are the specs for the laptop:
windows 7 x64
cpu: i7-2620M @ 2.7

[windows 7 i7-2620M screenshot](http://structureddomains.com/win7.png)

[windows 2012 xeon e5-1260 screenshot](http://structureddomains.com/win2012.png)

Comment: There are way too many variables at play here for us to give you a solid answer on this.. I would think.

Comment: Just wrote the same program in c++ with the same result. big variance on the server. Could it be some CPU setting? Is there some way to diagnose this? power saver setting or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measuring performance with `Stopwatch` is not too precise, especially on more advanced systems, because on advanced hardware the timing depends a lot on things that are not usually under direct control of your program, such as migrations between cores, priority of your processes and threads, cache affinity, state of various CPU pipelines, and so on.

Try adding these instructions ([from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61964/Performance-Tests-Precise-Run-Time-Measurements-wi)) before starting the stopwatch:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(2);
Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
```

This should make the measurements more consistent, especially on multi-core, multi-cpu boxes.

Comment: The Stopwatch should use QueryPerformanceCounter. So it should be pretty accurate. ProcessorAffinity seems to do the trick. So in this case it does actually execute faster, because it doesn't switch cores. I wonder if there's a way to tell it stay only on one core and not switch without specifying specific core?

Comment: @user2796794 You can use `GetCurrentProcessorNumber` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16525501/335858), and set affinity to `IntPtr(1 << procNumber)`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows desktops attribute higher priority to foreground processes, whereas Windows server attributes higher priority to background processes. This will be contributing to the differences you are experiencing.

Comment: The reason I started this research was because IIS was giving me crazy differences in response time for the same simple in memory only request processing. So it happens on background processes as well. Just wrote the same program in c++ with the same result. big variance on the server. Could it be some CPU setting?